# Android Zxing QR code scanner Vcalender issue with time zone

Tags: timezone, qr-code, vcalendar

I am using Zxing library for QR code scanner. My issue is dont getting Time zone value when scaning the QR code . QR code was created in the http://www.qrstuff.com/ website.

I am getting the data in hour-minute-second format like 20140717T135000Z. From this how can i calculate the time Zone!

For example

**Date 2014-06-07  05:00:00 with timeZone 5.30 GMT will produce the out put 20140607T103010
Also, 
date 2014-06-07  04:00:00 with timeZone 6.30 GMT will also produce the  same  out put 20140607T103010**

How can we find out the TimeZone value from this ?

​Screen shots are attached .

Please help​

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `Z` means UTC.  The QR generator that you're using is applying the selected time zone offset to the given value before it's rendered.

You should also know that vCalendar has been surpassed by iCalendar.